# In Mysql set date to one year later than current value, or one year from today

Tags: mysql

In mysql I had code to generate to 1 year + 1 day from today and then set expiryDate field (date datatype) to that for particular user

e.g

```
UPDATE fulllicense set expiryDate='2018-10-14' where userid=1;
```

but now I need to modify it so that if the current value of expiryDate is null or earlier than today to do as its currently doing but if later than today I want it to add a year and one day to the current value. So for example if the current value was 2017-12-17 I would want it set to 2018-12-18, I cannot work out how to do it in a single *update* statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IF`:

```
UPDATE fullllicense
SET expiryDate = DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(IF(expirydate IS NULL OR expirydate < CURDATE(), CURDATE(), expirydate),
                                   INTERVAL 1 YEAR),
                          INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `DATE_ADD` function. The `WHERE` clause it seems you already have handled, so I'll just use the one you included.

```
UPDATE fulllicense
    SET expiryDate = DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(expiryDate, INTERVAL 1 YEAR), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    WHERE userid = 1
AND expiryDate > NOW();
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: You're not checking whether the date is earlier than today's date.

Comment: Now you're not updating those rows at all. They're supposed to be updated to 1 year + 1 day from today.

Comment: "but if later than today I want it to add a year and one day to the current value. So for example if the current value was 2017-12-17 I would want it set to 2018-12-18" so if it's later than today (`expiryDate > NOW()`) then add 1 year and 1 day to the `expiryDate` (`SET expiryDate = DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(expiryDate, INTERVAL 1 YEAR), INTERVAL 1 DAY)`) no?

Comment: "if the current value of expiryDate is null or earlier than today to do as its currently doing"

Comment: And "currently doing" means "1 year + 1 day from today"

Comment: I respectfully disagree and that since he said "but if later than today..." so why would we add 1 year and 1 day regardless? However, let's let the OP clarify what they meant, because that's ultimately why we're here.

Comment: If the entrydate is less than today, set it to today+1 year + 1 day. If it's after today, add 1 year to it.

Comment: @KeithChason thx but doesnt this code only update expiry date if later than today, and nothing if ealier than today ?

Comment: Correct, which was my interpretation of the question, I thought it was supposed to "do as it was doing." But glad you got an answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE fulllicense 
   SET expiryDate = 
       CASE WHEN expiryDate IS NULL OR expiryDate < CURDATE()  
           THEN '2018-10-14' 
           ELSE 
                DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(expiryDate, INTERVAL 1 YEAR), INTERVAL 1 DAY) END
```